# How would I parse a time string to seconds in python?

Tags: python

Here are some examples of what the time strings would look like:

```
parse_time_string("20s") # 20
parse_time_string("30sec") # 30
parse_time_string("3m") # 180
parse_time_string("2min") # 120
parse_time_string("5h") # 18000
parse_time_string("1d") # 86400
```

Comment: What have you tried? A trivial approach would be `x.endswith(...)`, slicing, an `int()` cast and a multiplication.

Comment: I believe you forgot to post your research and code, and the *exact* issue you are facing.

Comment: AKX I've tried that but it leaves a very long function and i thought it could probably be done much better (maybe even with a library).

Comment: "some examples" Are these *all* the cases you need? What about `20 s`, `65seconds`, `5h 3min` or such? What exactly are the rules how these time strings are formed?

Comment: The time strings can't have spaces, and yes i would like to account for seconds, hours, hour, etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple approach using a regexp to split the string to the number and unit parts, and a bit of multiplication:

```
import re

multipliers = {
    "s": 1,
    "sec": 1,
    "m": 60,
    "min": 60,
    "h": 60 * 60,
    "d": 86400,
}


def parse_time_string(param):
    value, unit = re.match(r"^(\d+)([a-z]+)$", param).groups()
    return int(value) * multipliers[unit]


for example in ("20s", "30sec", "3m", "2min", "5h", "1d"):
    print(example, parse_time_string(example))
```

```
20s 20
30sec 30
3m 180
2min 120
5h 18000
1d 86400
```